# Is every model of MK (Morse-Kelley-Set-Theory) well-founded?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

On page 2 in ["The Hyperuniverse Project and Maximality"](https://books.google.de/books?id=KNBJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7&dq=hyperuniverse%20project&source=bl&ots=WJvA4mgnT_&sig=CDjsv0Na9NTig7ctEXgyQpORpF4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi87O_IiO3eAhWFjiwKHUWKCRYQ6AEwC3oECF0QAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) is written:

> The models $\mathcal{M}$ of MK are of the form $\langle M, \in, \mathcal{C} \rangle$, where $M$ is transitive model of ZFC, $\mathcal{C}$ the family of classes of $\mathcal{M}$ (i.e. every element of $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $M$) and $\in$ is the standard $\in$ relation.

Why can we assume that $M$  is transitive? If we knew, that every model of MK is well-founded, we could use the Mostowski collapse lemma. But is this the case?

Remark: In the book MK is formulated in a two-sorted version (have a look at the link).

Comment: By "model" read instead "standard model", these are the ones we typically want to consider. (But no, arbitrary models need not be well-founded.)

Comment: If there are set models at all, you can use compactness to get illfounded ones.

Comment: Or you can start with an illfounded model of ZFC+"there is an inaccessible", and show that it contains a model of MK, and that this model is illfounded (from the outside). :-)

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: I would suggest instead that you post an answer yourself explaining the situation, so that people who may have a similar question in the future may find this post.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I did it. Do you know if/how we can proof, that there are models of MK that are not isomorphic to a transitive model, without assuming the axiom of foundation at the background level?

Comment: Foundation is irrelevant. Just use compactness.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo But we use compactness to show there is an _illfounded_ model. In the last comment I asked for models that are not isomorphic to _transitive_ models...

Comment: Or can we directly use compactness to show that there are models not isomorphic to transitive ones?

Comment: A model is well-founded if and only if it is isomorphic to a transitive model. This is (essentially) Mostowski's collapsing theorem.

Comment: I know only the direction well-founded -> transitive. Where can I find a proof of the other implication?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. Fair enough, sorry for not catching up sooner. Well, the compactness argument gives you that the natural numbers of the model are ill-founded, and this suffices. Perhaps it may help to think about this as follows: Any model of set theory (without foundation) contains an inner model that satisfies foundation (the class of well-founded sets). To verify that the model is not transitive, it suffices to show that this inner model is ill-founded. To show this, it suffices that the natural numbers are ill-founded. And this is what the usual compactness argument ensures.

Comment: "To verify that the model is not transitive, it suffices to show that this inner model is ill-founded" Can you explain why?

Comment: If the model is transitive, its inner model is as well. But its inner model is not even well-founded; recall we have Mostowski's theorem for the inner model, since it satisfies foundation.

Comment: Let M be your model and N the inner model in M. Since N satisfies foundation, you can use Mostowski's theorem _inside_ M. And since our N (the class of well-founded sets) is a transitive class (with respect to M) the Mostowski collapsing function is the identity. So what do we get out of it?

Comment: You do not apply Mostowki's internally, of course.

Comment: But why can we apply it externally? (We should clean up our discussion after I'm de-confused ;-)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm going to ask a new question with my problem. Maybe we should delete all our comments except your first three!?

Comment: I would just leave them. If a moderator finds them unnecessary they will clean them up at some point anyway.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. Thank you for insisting on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Caicedo pointed out in the comments by "models" only "standard models" are meant. The argument that there are illfounded models of MK is exactly the same as for ZFC (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148634/show-that-there-are-non-well-founded-models-of-zermelo-fraenkel-set-theory)). If we assume the axiom of foundation at the background level such an illfounded model is necessarily not isomorphic to a transitive model. If we don't have foundation in the metatheory this is not always the case (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017399/without-foundation-not-transitive-model-of-zfc)).