# Without foundation: Not transitive model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

Let's assume that ZFC is consistent.

It is easy to show that there is an illfounded model (with compactness, e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40821/existence-of-an-omega-nonstandard-model-of-zfc-from-compactness)). If we have the axiom of foundation at the background level we can conclude that such a model is not isomorphic to a transitive model.

Is it possible to show that there is a model of ZFC that is not isomorphic to a transitive model *without* assuming foundation at the background level?

Comment: That's a nice question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice question! The answer is **no**: Foundation is indeed needed in the metatheory.

Boffa's antifoundation axiom implies that every extensional directed graph $(X; \rightarrow)$ is isomorphic to $(A;\in\upharpoonright A)$ for some transitive set $A$. In particular, *any* model of ZFC is isomorphic to a transitive model - at least, that's what ZFC-Foundation+Boffa thinks.

Note that the only thing being used here is that ZFC is extensional, so the above also applies to e.g. Quine's theory NF and its variants. Even for non-extensional theories, we get a version of the above result: we get that if $T$ is a consistent $\{\in\}$-theory then $T$ has a model of the form $(A;\in\upharpoonright A)$ for some set $A$.

For a discussion of Boffa's axiom, see Chapter $5$ of [Aczel's book](http://www.irafs.org/courses/materials/aczel_set_theory.pdf).

Comment: You mean ZFC-Foundation+Boffa proves "If ZFC has a model, then every model is isomorphic to a transitive model.", right?

Comment: And do you know if there is a (finitistic) proof of Con(ZFC-Foundation) $\Rightarrow$ Con(ZFC-Foundation+Boffa)?

Comment: @PopovFlorino "If ZFC has a model, then every model is isomorphic to a transitive model." Yes (although what I wrote is also true, it's just weaker). As to relative consistency, I believe that it does - the point being that any model $M$ of ZFC interprets a model of ZFC-Foundation+Boffa consisting more-or-less of the extensional graphs in $M$.

Comment: I think you should state this in a stronger form: *Any* model is isomorphic to a transitive model. I am quite surprised this holds.

Comment: (Of course, the point is that being transitive means less now. But still.)

Comment: Yes, thank you. What a weird thing, to have transitivity mean less than well-foundedness.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do you know other papers about Boffa's axiom?

Comment: @Popov The original reference contains a proof of the consistency of the system. [MR0476514 (57 #16074)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=476514) Boffa, Maurice. *Forcing et négation de l'axiome de fondement*. Acad. Roy. Belg. Cl. Sci. Mém. Coll. in-8∘ (2) **40** (1972), no. 7, 52 pp.

Comment: @PopovFlorino Not a ton, sadly! It's not as popular as Aczel's antifoundation axiom. I think the Holmes-Forster-Libert article "Alternative set theories" in [the Handbook of the History of Logic (vol. 6)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZF_QckMFy-oC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a good starting place.