# Is the axiom of regularity really needed to prove this ordered pair property?

Tags: set-theory

There is a definition of ordered pairs such that $(a,b)$= $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$. Using the axiom of regularity, which states that every non-empty set has a member which is disjoint from the set, we can prove the ordered pair property for that construction. Is it really necessary? That is, is there a model of $ZFC$ - $Regularity$ where that construction does not have the ordered pair property?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there are two sets $a\ne c$ such that $a=\{c\}$ and $c=\{a\}$, then with that funny definition of ordered pairs we would have
$$(a,a)=\{a,\{a,a\}\}=\{a,\{a\}\}=\{a,c\}=\{c,a\}=\{c,\{c\}\}=\{c,\{c,c\}\}=(c,c).$$
I've been told that such a pair of sets can exist in a model of ZFC minus Regularity.

Comment: +1 - the other half of this answer is of course that such a situation can indeed occur, which takes an argument.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That would take someone who knows set theory to write an answer.

Comment: Oh indeed, I just wanted to point out to the OP that that is something which needs to be said.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't want to say it myself because it's something I only know by hearsay. Why don't you write a proper answer with some indication of how such "antifoundation" models are constructed? Do you just start with a set of two atoms $\{a,c\}$ with the stipulation that $a\in c\in a$ and build up a cumulative hierarchy from that?

Comment: I actually don't know the details, although my vague memory is it's not hard. But I think what you've written is a complete enough answer to the question: it explains how in the absence of regularity there are seemingly-permitted configurations which break the ordered pair property.

Comment: For a simple example of a model where this holds, start with a model $(V,\in)$ of ZF and then take the model $\hat V$ with domain $V$ and membership relation $\hat\in$ identical to $\in$ except that (1) $0$ has exactly one $\hat\in$-element which is $\{0\}$, and (2) $\{\{0\}\}$ is $\hat\in$-empty. Then taking $a=0$ and $c=\{0\},$ we have $a=\{c\}$ and $c=\{a\}$ in $\hat V.$ It's straightforward, if confusing, to check that $\hat V$ satisfies all of ZF except regularity.

Comment: To be honest, almost all the literature on ill-founded set theory I know of is either about NF(ish stuff) or Aczel's antifoundation axiom AFA. Neither of these helps; in particular, AFA implies that $a=\{b\}$ and $b=\{a\}$ holds iff $a=b$. If I recall correctly, *Boffa's* antifoundation axiom does give rise to a "nontrivial double Quine atom," but it's hard to find literature on BAFA.

Comment: Actually, I guess see the references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3017529/28111). :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber  "AFA implies that $a=\{b\}$ and $b=\{a\}$ holds iff $a=b$"? You didn't mean "iff", did you? You meant "only if"? Otherwise AFA is weirder than I thought. :-)

Comment: @bof Oh god ... :P