# Is Infinite descending sequence reverse of construction of Zermelo ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I wonder how do they deduce "Infinite descending sequence of sets" from "Axiom of Regularity". So, how one imagine and say hey people! there is this "infinite descending chain" and we should avoid it?

So, when i see Zermelo ordinals, i realized that they are infinitely ascending chains.

$$ 0 = \{ \}, $$
$$ 1 = \{0\} = \{\{ \}\}, $$
$$ 2 = \{1\} = \{\{\{ \}\}\},$$
$$ n = \{n−1\} = \{\{\{...\}\}\}, $$

Thus, i think when they(Zermelo et al.) try it in reverse order so bigger number to smaller number they got infinite descending chains like -1,-2,-3,...

**Question 1**: Would this right or "Infinite descending sequence of set" are some usual thing without requiring this realization by Zermelo et al.?

**Question 2**: Does Infinitely descending sequence relates to negative numbers(-1,-2,-3,...) this way or not how?

**Question 3**: So, then they proposed the well ordering theorem this way, right? There should be a minimal element, an maximum is not accepted, right?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking how negative numbers are represented in set theory without violating regularity, or are you asking about the motivation for allowing ascending but not descending sequences, or something else?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I am asking about the motivation how descending sequences not allowed? Also, i want to know how negative numbers could be represented without violating axiom of regularity?

Answer (score 3):

Implementing ill-founded structures in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - such as $(\mathbb{Z}:<)$ - is straightforward as soon as we realize that there's no reason to look for too *simple* implementations. For example, we can define $\mathbb{Z}$ in terms of $\mathbb{N}$ and basic set-theoretic operations: we treat an integer as an equivalence class of pairs of natural numbers with respect to the relation $$(a,b)\sim (c,d)\quad\iff\quad a+d=c+b$$ (intuitively, $(x,y)$ means $x-y$). Similarly, rationals are defined in terms of pairs of integers, reals are defined in terms of sets of rationals, and so forth. The point is to get away from the idea that order has to be generated by $\in$: while sometimes we can make that work, we don't want to commit to it too much.

*Incidentally, nobody really uses the Zermelo ordinals anymore except in very rare situations; the von Neumann ordinals are the things to focus on first. For example, they generalize to the transfinite more naturally, and their ordering is simpler to define (it's just $\in$).*

The basic takeaway is that we don't *need* ill-founded sets for anything: a rich enough structure of well-founded sets can implement ill-founded structures.

---

As to why we actively focus on well-founded sets, this comes down to a philosophical point. To avoid Russell's paradox, we want some intuition about the universe of sets which constrains what sort of comprehension (= set formation) we can have. There are various ways to do this (consider e.g. $\mathsf{NFU}$ or $\mathsf{GPK^+_\infty}$), but the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ approach is to start with the idea of a **cumulative hierarchy**. And we trivially only get well-founded sets that way.

- This is not to say that by ruling out ill-founded sets we escape Russell's paradox! **Adding axioms never makes a theory more consistent**. Rather, the idea of the cumulative hierarchy - which trivially rules out ill-founded sets as a byproduct - motivates a particular set of axioms, the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-axioms or some variant thereof ($\mathsf{ZF}$, $\mathsf{Z}$, $\mathsf{ZC}$, ...), in which Russell's paradox fails to go through.

That said, there's no rule saying that we can't consider versions of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without regularity/foundation. The relevant term here is **antifoundation axiom**; the best known one is Aczel's, but I personally find Boffa's equally interesting (although it leads to some rather odd results - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3017529/28111)).

Comment: The second to last paragraph seems dangerous considering that it's a very common misconception that foundation (as opposed to restricted comprehension) gets ZFC out of Russell's paradox.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That's a good point; I've edited to (hopefully!) address that.

Comment: That's fine we should not use Zermelo ordinals. But what about $-1,-2,-3,...$ sequence, is it an infinite descending sequence? And well ordering theorem also relates to infinite ascending sequences and requires a minimum, is this right?

Comment: @lockedscope It’s an infinite descending sequence in the order on the integers but it’s not an infinite descending sequence in the membership relation. Only the latter is forbidden by foundation. In the  implementation of the signed integers that Noah gives in his answer (or any possible implementation in ZF), the ordering is not given by the membership relation.

Comment: So negative sequence -1,-2,-3,... is not allowed because of well ordering principle and well ordering theorem or infinite descending sequence of membership is unrelated here, is that right?

Comment: @lockedscope I don't understand your most recent. Ill-founded structures pose no problem for $\mathsf{ZFC}$, they just have to be implemented in a way *other than* using $\in$ for the ill-founded relation.

Comment: @lockedscope Not sure what you mean by -1,-2,-3,... not being "allowed". It's allowed. It's how the integers work... they have infinite descending sequences in their order... no problem with that. The well ordering principle only applies to the naturals, or more generally to subsets of the integers that are bounded from below.