# Can we build a relative constructible hierarchy over a hereditarily non-Dedekindian set, that models the existence of that set + ZF-Reg.?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose we have a transitive model $M$ of "ZF -Reg. + there exists a set that is hereditarily non-dedekindian". [here the ambient theory in which models are construced is ZF-Reg. + Boffa's anti-foundation axiom].

Where non-Dedekindian set means a set for which there do not exist an injection from it to a proper subset of it nor there exists an injection from it to the set $\omega$ of all von Neumann naturals. [so non-Dedekindian actually means a set that is both Tarski-infinite and Dedekind-finite]

Let $A$ be the transitive closure of some hereditarily non-Dedekindian set in $M$.

Now if we raise a constructible hierarchy $L^M_A$ over $A$ relative to $M$, that is we we build:

$L^M_{0,A}= A$

$L^M_{\alpha+1, A} = \mathcal P^M_{def} (L_{\alpha,A})$

$L^M_{\lambda,A}= \bigcup _{\alpha < \lambda} L^M_{\alpha,A}$, for $\lambda$ limit.

Suppose the well founded height of $M$ is $\kappa$, that is $\kappa$ is the class of all ordinals in $M$.

Questions:

- Is it always the case that $L^M_{\kappa,A}$ is a model of "ZF-Reg.+ there exists a hereditarily non-Dedkindian set"?
- If not, then is it always the case that we can find an ordinal $\zeta > \kappa $ such that we continue building the hierarchy over $M$ as to get a model $M^+$ of ZF-Reg. whose well founded height is $\zeta$, and at the same time have an ordinal $\gamma \leq \zeta$ such that $L^{M^+}_{\gamma,A}$ be a model of ZF-Reg.+ there exists a hereditarily non-Dedekindian set?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of non-Dedekindian set. What is the difference between Dedekind-finite set and non-Dedekindian set?

Comment: How can a transitive $M$ contain a hereditarily infinite non-Dedekind-finite set?

Comment: I think what you actually want is just that $M$ contains no nonstandard ordinals.

Comment: I know that you enjoy coming up with terminology, but as I mentioned before, it makes it very hard to understand your questions. The term is "Dedekind-finite".

Comment: @NoahSchweber, your terminology is confusing me. Do you mean that a transitive M cannot contain among its elements a set that is non-Dedekindian (notice that non-Dedekindian means a Tarski infinite set that is Dedekind finite)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I thought that ZF-Reg. is consistent with the existence of a set $A$ that is hereditarily equinumerous to $x$ for whatever $x$ is. Now take $x$ to be some non-Dedekindian set, then $A$ would hereditarily non-Dedekindian.  So why there cannot exist a transitive model of ZF that contains $A$ among its elements?

Comment: @HanulJeon, The definition that I know of about *Dedekind-finite* is not being Dedekind infinite [see for example wikipedia on that matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set ], and this is not necessarily the non-Dedekindian I'm speaking about. A non-Dedekindian set is a Dedekind finite set that is Tarski infinite. While a Dedekind-finite set can be a Tarski finite set.

Comment: @Zuhair A transitive model is, a fortiori, well-founded. Your $A$ is obviously ill-founded - it's not the "infinite Dedekind-finite" bit that's problematic, it's the "**hereditarily**" which is the problem. No model with such an $A$ can possibly be transitive.

Comment: @Zuhair $\mathsf{ZF}$-$\mathsf{Reg}$ being consistent with something doesn't mean that there is a **transitive** model of $\mathsf{ZF}$-$\mathsf{Reg}$ in which that thing is true. Your leap from the existence of a model to the existence of a transitive model is unjustified.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, a transitive model of ZF would be well founded, this I can understand; but why should a transitive model of ZF-Reg. be well founded? You seem to be implying that ZF-Reg.+some anti-foundation axiom cannot have transitive model. I thought that ZF-Reg+ there exists a nonempty set of quine atoms can have a transitive model?

Comment: @Zuhair When we say "transitive model of $X$" without elaboration, the default assumption is that the **metatheory** is $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Since regularity holds in the metatheory, every transitive model of anything whatsoever is well-founded - and so yes, $\mathsf{ZF}$-$\mathsf{Reg}$+[antifoundation] cannot have a transitive model. If we change the metatheory this of course changes, but then [it's not clear what the value of transitive models actually is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017399/without-foundation-not-transitive-model-of-zfc). What do **you** mean by "transitive model"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, of course the metatheory is ZF-Reg. And the link you've supplied shows that [under Boffa's AFA] we can have a transitive model of any model. So my model -> transitive model move is granted by BAFA. The value is that the membership relation looks more natural, that's all.

Comment: @Zuhair "of course the metatheory is ZF-Reg" Why would that be assumed? If you talk about transtive models without any explicit comment on the metatheory, the default assumption - **as usual** - is that the metatheory is $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, by transitive model of theory T I mean a transitive set that satisfies T.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, OK then I admit that the "of course" part is not correct. But what I mean, is that it is obvious that the metatheory cannot be ZFC for the definition I'm making, because I'm deliberately depending on a non-well founded set, that's the main tool of the argument, it's too non-well founded to be suitable to be grounded in a model that has ZFC as its meta-theory. I'll make a remark that the meta-theory is not ZFC, it is ZF-Reg.+BAFA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117152/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-zuhair).